# Can I connect my iPhone to mac to run terminal commands?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, monterey

So I’m running IOS 15.1, I was wondering if there was a way I could connect my iPhone to mac and run terminal commands from my iPhone on my mac. Right now, I’m running MacOs Monterey Beta.

Comment: Turn on Remote Login in Sharing in the Mac and use a ssh client in the iPhone to connect to the Mac.